# How to export c++ vector to excel?

Tags: c++, excel, file, vector, export

As the question states, how would I export a vector generated by a C++ script to an excel sheet? I have looked at the answers related to C# and I am unfamiliar with the methods outlined. How is this done in C++?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest CSV format which is simple text and can be easily imported by excel.

Comment: I don't doubt that I will end up doing this. However, thus far I've only used C++ for the functionalities that it shares with Matlab and am unfamiliar with certain basics. Is CSV format something to save the output to?

Comment: yes, CSV is a very simple text format (Comma Separated Values). I think you will easily find documentation on internet.

Answer (score 2):

You can write C++ functions that act just like Excel native functions and accept or return range arguments.
Long story: [Dalton's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470027975) gives the complete story and explores in great detail the many ways to interface Excel with C++. Complete and well written but 600 pages so may not be ideal if you want something up and running quickly.
Short story: I wrote a [tutorial](http://linkedin.com/pulse/exporting-c-code-excel-quick-painless-tutorial-antoine-savine) for my students and colleagues that should get you to interface Excel with C++ within an hour.
Both are geared towards applications in finance, but the programming applies to any field.
I hope it helps.